# Delete the manually created iOS Development certificate and generate from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

Can we delete the existing manually generated iOS development Certificate and re-generate using the XCode? If then, can you please share me the steps need to be taken for that? So, it does not conflict when using same mailid to generate iOS dev cert and provisioning profile from XCode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Deleting existing certificate**

1. Open `Keychain Access`
2. On the left side from `Keychains` select `login` and from `Category` select `My Certificate`
3. Look for your development certificates.
4. Right click on it and delete it.

[image]

**Create development certificates from Xcode.**

1. Go to Xcode preferences.
2. Go to `Accounts` tab and select the apple id.
3. Click `Manage certificates`
4. And create new certificates.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the one you informed me for local machine. Moreover, can we also revoke/cancel the dev-certificate I have created on Apple Developer Portal and thereafter generate from XCode?

Comment: Just login to your developer.apple account and revoke the certificates. Or you can also create new ones and leave the current ones.

Comment: Thanks Bilal. We can create a new one with same email id/Name also? And may I know while generating the dev certificates from XCode where would we get the certificate in-order to bind the same to Apple Dev Portal?

Comment: Once Xcode creates certificates it automatically appears in your Apple developer account. And you can export the certificates from you mac KeyChain.